# Float a table at right when there is enough space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I will let the picture talk by it self. 
[image: thedream.png]
The left one is how it looks like now. 
The right one is how I would like it to look like assuming the resolution is enough to fit the table. Else the table should be under the fields.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4hn9dgb/1/)

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Header</strong></h4>

    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="f1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field 1:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="f1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="f2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field 2:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="f2" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="f3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field 3:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="f3" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="f4" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field 4</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="f4" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Header 1</th>
              <th>Header 2</th>
              <th>Header 3</th>
              <th>Header 4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="active">
              <th>Item 1</th>
              <td>0.08</td>
              <td>EUR</td>
              <td>100.10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Item 2</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Item 3</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Item 4</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>0.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
              <th>Item Total Value</th>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Item 5</th>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
              <th>VAT</th>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Item 6</th>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your CSS?

Comment: Can You edit your HTML code, because I might find a solution modyfiing HTML code?

Comment: I have created a link to JSFiddle where you can see the code in action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I would wrap your `.form-group` DIVs and your `.table-responsive` DIV in their own DIV with the appropriate `col-*-*` class.

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group></div>
    <div class="form-group></div>
    <div class="form-group></div>
    <div class="form-group></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="table-responsive"></div>
</div>
```

See your updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4hn9dgb/3/

Note that I adjusted the classes on the DIV wrappers of the `<input>`s to `col-md-10` so that the label and DIV wrapper total 12 columns. This will ensure that they take up the full width of their parent `.col-md-6` DIV.

There might be some fine-tuning but this looks like what you need.

Comment: yes, i did, but then, the table goes on the right side of the screen UNDER the fields.. not next to them

Comment: Then try my second option, have you tried nesting grids?

Comment: just did.. we are getting close. (you mean table-responsive pull-right). Indeed the table goes right but i have other UI issues. 1) Now the fields are under their labels . When the table goes to right the fields are resized (smaller) and there is a huge gap between the table and the fields. I wasn' t aware of "form-group-container". thanks

Comment: Just updated answer, please check and check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4hn9dgb/3/). `.form-group-container` is a class I made up.

Comment: The table may go to the right side but then the fields are messed up. There  is a huge ugly gap between the fields and the table (resolution over 900px approx)

Comment: @Pitelk you need to do a little homework, we cannot do it all for you. Look into the different column classes of the [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). You can set multiple column classes, `.col-sm-8 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4` among other options.

Comment: I think that the "pull-left" is not needed after all. The behavior us the same even if you remove it. Is there something i am missing?

Comment: @Pitelk yes, you are correct about the `.pull-left`. I will remove that, that was left over from my first answer. Not sure if you want percentage widths or not, since you're using Bootstrap I'm thinking that you do, but you could also set a max-width on the form groups like you have the table, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/a4hn9dgb/4/). The example removed the `.col-*-*` classes and uses `.pull-left` on each container DIV.

Answer (score 1):

I just added `<div class="col-md-8">` this tag **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/a4hn9dgb/2/)**

```
<div class="container">

             <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Header</strong></h4>
     <div class="col-md-8"> 
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="f1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field 1:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="f1" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="f2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field 2:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="f2" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="f3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field 3:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="f3" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="f4" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field 4</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="f4" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Header 1</th>
                                <th>Header 2</th>
                                <th>Header 3</th>
                                <th>Header 4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <th>Item 1</th>
                                <td>0.08</td>
                                <td>EUR</td>
                                <td>100.10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Item 2</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Item 3</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Item 4</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>USD</td>
                                <td>0.1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <th>Item Total Value</th>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Item 5</th>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <th>VAT</th>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Item 6</th>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                    </div>
            </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: When the table goes to right the fields (at the left) are resized (smaller) and there is a huge gap between the table and the fields...I tried various col-xx-yy combinations, but nothing worked

Comment: change <div class="col-md-8">  to <div class="col-md-6">

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a container div which contains `.form-group` then add `float:left` to your new container div.

```
 .your-new-container{
    float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a styling issue, you will have to edit the CSS in order to fix this.